# Microsoft ActiveDirectory PowerShell Module (Microsoft RSAT Download) Isn't Thread-Safe ("invalid enumeration context" exception) - Remedy?

Tags: c#, multithreading, powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

The PowerShell ActiveDirectory module doesn't seem to be thread-safe.

We wrote a .NET Framework service. The code opens a PowerShell Runspace (NuGet package [`System.Management.Automation.dll`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation.dll/)) that's executing a PowerShell script which queries Active Directory by means of [Active Directory Web Services (ADWS)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/04/06/active-directory-web-services-overview/).

Our service spawns a number of threads, so tasks can be processed in parallel. If two threads query Active Directory in parallel (e.g. by both running the `Get-ADUser` Cmdlet), Active Directory Web Services (ADWS) throws an "`invalid enumeration context`" SOAP exception.

**Did we perhaps misconfigure our Windows domain controller? Or is this a fault that's supposed to be reported to Microsoft? Where would I report this error?**

On **GitHub** I [created a repository containing an example console application](https://github.com/SetTrend/powershell-test), making it easy to reproduce this issue. On **UserVoice** I [submitted a corresponding "idea"](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/38573491-activedirectory-powershell-module-isn-t-thread-saf).

Comment: Can you post your full stack trace in your question?  It's unclear how you're getting that the AD module isn't thread-safe.

Comment: I assume there is a reason you can't just use LDAP or LDAPS via `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher`? That's far easier to use via C#.

Comment: If you absolutely must use ADWS, you can try consuming the web service directly from C#. Microsoft doesn't have any documentation on how to do it, but [this guy figured it out](http://samirvaidya.blogspot.com/2012/06/using-active-directory-web-services-in.html). (Calling PowerShell from C# is always awful - I've had to do it, and I've learned to avoid it like the plague)

Comment: For those of you who don't want to run the repo, I added a screenshot now, depicting the PowerShell script and the error messages caused by the code. We're considering using the DirectoryServices namespace now. But it took several expensive weeks for us to analyze the cause of the issue. This question here serves three main purposes: (1) others running into the same situation may find it helpful, (2) we may have made a configuration/programming mistake using ActiveDirectory module and would like to know, (3) Microsoft is supposed to fix this issue.

Comment: You are asking too much from that poor server, 250 queries at once.

Comment: If you lower the number of `Get-ADUser` calls in the script file and lower the number of threads, the same will happen. It's just a matter of hitting the right moment when two `Get-ADUser` calls interfere with each other. That's a transient issue, so I raised both parameters in order for anyone willing to reproduce the issue to hit the exception right in the first place. If you lower the number of threads to 3, lower the `Get-ADUser` calls to 2 and lower the delay between launching new threads in `Main()` you'll hit the same exception.Or you may accidentally miss it+need to run multiple times.

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze - BTW: It's not 250 calls. Each of the `Get-ADUser` calls is done sequentially. So there's never more calls then threads. How did you compute the 250 queries you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error earlier today on our PS scripts which also use RSAT and run in parallel. Our solution was to simply use a mutex around the RSAT cmdlets.

```
$mutex = New-Object Threading.Mutex($false, "AD Operation");
$mutex.WaitOne();
try {
  Get-ADObject ...
}
finally {
  $mutex.ReleaseMutex();
  $mutex.Dispose();
}
```

The mutual exclusion, in this case, is handled by the SO (Windows) on the context of the SO itself, so it will work across both threads and processes.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach contradict the purpose of parallelism? What if two machines execute this script?

Comment: @AxD, this is a valid concern, but not really, unless your script is all about performing AD operations. Other operations done by the script will still be executed in parallel, being forced to serialize only when performing operations on AD via these RSAT cmdlets. For example: my script deploys hundreds of objects on Azure (parallel) and then perform operations on AD (now serialized).
When running on different machines, the "thread safe" problem isn't a problem anymore, since there's no shared memory between the threads (they're on different machines!) and the AD server itself is thread safe.